# Bitshift Operator Used on Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax, operators

I've been trying to teach myself Javascript lately and I'm noticing several slightly quirky syntax choices used by various different authors. Usually I can figure them out, but this one's stumped me a bit.

[The author of the post here](http://css-tricks.com/colorpeek-part-2-building-first-chrome-extension/) creates an empty object, colors, which will contain a set of properties for each background color in the page. Each color property will have a value equal to the total area covered by that color. To do this, he uses the following syntax:

```
// ...set or override it in the colors object,
// adding the current element area to the
// existing value.
colors[bgColor] = (colors[bgColor] >> 0) + nodeArea;
```

At this point, the property named by the value of bgColor may or may not be present in the object. The intent of the expression in the parenthesis is presumably to return the running total or 0 if this is the first time the color is seen. My question is, is this the right shift operator being overloaded and I'm searching for the wrong name, or why does the right shift behave this way?

Comment: A more common idiom would be `colors[bgColor] || 0`.

Comment: Please note what Barmar says. Using `||` is fairly common. Using `>>` is uncommon to the point that I have literally never seen it, and I read a ton of source code.

Comment: Yeah. This looks like something he noticed in an obfuscated code contest, and decided to use in production code just to be clever.

Comment: As the quality answers below hint, the way to see this is not that its an issue of understanding bitwise operations so much as understanding javascript type coercion.

Comment: The code actually looks somewhat _nooby_ for lack of a better term. He also doesn't cache the length when parsing _the entire DOM tree_, but when I saw that I though "he's just trying to make it easy for inexperienced javascript programmers". Then he does this bitwise weirdness which, as @Barmar says, is totally uncommon and there's a simple idiom that would have actually taught newcomers to javascript something useful.

Comment: @Barmar upon looking into it. There *IS* actually an interesting difference between `||` and `>>`. If the LHS is not a number it will coerce to NaN and 0 is passed through so `({}) || 0 !== 0` but `({}) || 0 === 0`. So feel free to use that the one time in a million when it actually applies.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer: I think you meant `({}) || 0 !== 0` (whereas `({}) >> 0 === 0`), and good point. I don't think that's what the author of the code above meant, but it remains a good point.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer That's true, but practically irrelevant. Variables that are supposed to hold a number don't somehow end up with an object in them. The only special case you have to worry about is the initial value, which defaults to `undefined`.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer nice one but, it doesn't seem like `colors[bgColor] || 0` would not have worked here and adding such an exotic approach to doing this in a code sample intended for _beginners_ is just terrible.

Comment: Oh I absolutely agree - just an interesting to note for us commentors

Comment: I just noticed the name of the site: css-tricks.com. Maybe he likes "tricky" code.

Comment: @Barmar: LOL, no, Chris is a CSS whiz but not much of a JS guy. (Don't know about Tyler Sticka, as it's a guest post, so not by Chris.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The intent of the expression in the parenthesis is presumably to return the running total or 0 if this is the first time the color is seen. My question is, is this the right shift operator being overloaded and I'm searching for the wrong name, or why does the right shift behave this way?

It's not overloaded (JavaScript doesn't have operator overloading). It's relying on the fact that `undefined >> 0` is `0` and `anyNumber >> 0` is `anyNumber` (caveats to follow). If the property doesn't exist yet, looking it up yields `undefined`, and so `>> 0` turns that into `0`. If the property *is* defined and contains a whole number that fits in 32 bits, `>> 0` returns the number without changing it. (If the number has a fractional part, it's truncated, and if it doesn't fit in 32 bits, it's [wrapped](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.5) if I'm reading that right, but I don't think that's what the coder is trying to do.) So by doing that, then adding the area, they are indeed adding to a running total (or initializing it if it isn't there yet).

It's mostly a shorthand version of:

```
if (colors[bgColor]) {
    colors[bgColor] += nodeArea;
}
else {
    colors[bgColor] = nodeArea;
}
```

...(as any falsey value `>> 0` is `0`) but with the added feature that it will always result in a non-`NaN` number provided `nodeArea` is a non-`NaN` number, whereas with some truthy non-number values for `colors[bgColor]` (`{}`, for instance), the "long" version above would result in a string or in `NaN`.

Comment: Note that because of the nuance I noted in the comment on the question, its actually more along the lines of `if(!_.isNumber(colors[bgColor]))` where `_.isNumber` is taken from underscorejs. For the vast majority of situations this difference will almost certainly not matter

Comment: @GeorgeMauer: LOL, I was just flagging that up as well. Good comment, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is just one of the tricks to avoid an `if` condition. When you create the property with the value in `bgColor`, you might do something like this

```
if (colors[bgColor] === undefined) {
    colors[bgColor] = 0;
}
colors[bgColor] += nodeArea;
```

This is is to make sure that the initial value is 0, if the `bgColor` is not there in `colors`, otherwise `undefined` will be the value. So, to avoid that, if we can convert `undefined` to `0` we can simply avoid that `if` condition.

```
console.log(undefined >> 0);
# 0
```

So, `colors[bgColor] >> 0` will be 0 if `bgColor` is not already defined, otherwise the actual value as it is, since right shifting by zero doesn't change the actual value.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You are right, I just changed it to simply `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

It might be an attempt to cast the color value as a 32-bit value, since Javascript normally stores all values as IIRC 64-bit floats (with 53 bit precision), but on bitwise operations it treats them as 32-bit integers. This might be an attempt to force the value to be treated as such before adding NodeArea.

I think it also forces it to be interpreted as a Number, but the implicit type of NodeArea would have that effect as well, normally.

edit - T.J. Crowder also makes another point which I tried to find from MDN but didn't: the return value of the operation if the property doesn't exist would be 0, thus setting the value as well). In face his whole post makes a good point :P.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah I _knew_ I had that wrong :P fixing it now, ty.

Comment: (You're very kind. :-) )